# Find $p$ such that the integral is finite

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$. For which $p \in[1, \infty)$ it holds that $f \in L^{p}(X)$ when $f(x)=|x|^{-1}$ and

- $X=B(0,1)$
- $X=\mathbb{R}^{n} \backslash B(0,1)$
- $X=\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

**My attempt**:

Suppose $0\leq a<b\leq \infty$ and we consider the annulus $E_{a,b}:=\{x\in\Bbb{R}^n\,:\, a<|x|<b\}$. Then, for any $p\in\Bbb{R}, $  we have $\int_{E_{a,b}}\frac{1}{|x|^{p}}\,dx=\int_a^b\frac{1}{r^{p}}A_{n-1}r^{n-1}\,dr=A_{n-1}\int_a^b\frac{1}{r^{p+1-n}}\,dr$, where $A_{n-1}$ is the surface area of the unit sphere $S^{n-1}\subset\Bbb{R}^n$

$A_{n-1} \frac{-(p+1-n)}{r^{p+2-n}}\bigr\vert_{a}^{b}$

In the first case, $a = 0$ and $b = 1$, in the second case $a = 1$ and $b = \infty$, and in the third case $a = 0$ and $b = \infty$. In the first case the integral is finite when $p +2 ≤ n$, in the second case the integral is finite when $p + 2 ≥ n$, and in the third case $p + 2 = n$.

Is my attempt correct?

Comment: No. You want to check the integral of $1/r^{\lambda+1-n}$ and the conclusion. The cases $a=0,b=1$ and $a=1,b=\infty$ are fundamentally different. Also what about  $p\ne 1$?

Comment: Does $\lambda$ equal $p$ ?

Comment: @Simon Yes it does, I've edited

Comment: It might be clearer just to replace all $\lambda$s by $p$s, since they are the same thing ?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. You should not delete the question. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

For any $\lambda\in \Bbb{R}$,

- $\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^{\lambda}}\,dx$ is finite if and only if $\lambda<1$.
- $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{\lambda}}\,dx$ is finite if and only if $\lambda>1$.
- clearly, $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{\lambda}}\,dx$ is finite if and only if $\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^{\lambda}}\,dx$ and $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{\lambda}}\,dx$ are both finite. This happens if and only if $\lambda<1$ and $\lambda>1$.... i.e this integral is never finite.

Now, take $\lambda=p+1-n$ and conclude.

Comment: These integral convergence criteria are EXTREMELY fundamental, so never forget them. Also, their proofs are literally by direct calculation which is why I didn't include them.

Comment: Why isn't it greater/less than or equal to?

Comment: @Silver54 because it's just not true. What is $\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}\,dx$? What is $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}\,dx$? what is $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}\,dx$?

Comment: So the answer would be $p < n$, $p > n$ and $p = \emptyset$? For cases 1, 2, and 3 respectively

Comment: @Silver54 yes for first two (strictly speaking, the first should say $1\leq p<n$, since you're imposing the requirement that $p\in [1,\infty)$). For the third, $p$ is a number, it can't equal the empty set. Just say in words that the third integral is never finite.